# Django: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: django, exception

I am new to Django and trying to pass an author's name to a view and filter out quote objects based on the author's name. here are the codes:

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='unknown')
    author_info = models.TextField(max_length=1000)


class Quote(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    quote = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^quotes/(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'quotes.views.quotesbyauthor'),
```

views.py

```
def quotesbyauthor(request, name):
    aquotelist = Quote.objects.filter(author__exact = name)
    return render_to_response(quotes_by_author.html, {'aquotelist': aquotelist })
```

However I get this error when I try to get http://127.0.0.1:8000/quotes/you/
('you' is a test author object, already created)

```
ValueError at /quotes/you/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'you'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/quotes/you/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'you'

Exception Location:     /home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 479
Python Executable:  /home/qliq/djenv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/qliq/djenv/quoteapp',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/home/qliq/djenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

I appreciate your help to resolve this.

Comment: Is it just a paste error that your .html template has no quotes around it?

Comment: Also please post a more complete traceback as it should be telling you a specific line and context of the error. Try setting name to a default keyword like quotesbyauthor(request, name='')

Comment: @jdi, I updated the question with a more detailed error message. Also, I added quotes around the template name, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You want to search on the author's `author_name` field, not the id.

```
Quote.objects.filter(author__author_name=name)
```

With your current search, `author__exact`, Django expects `name` to be the id of the author, so gives an error because `you` is not an integer.

Comment: gah I totally overlooked that one when I was commenting above. Good eye :-)

Comment: As per U-DON's answer, he does actually name his attribute author_name so that filter needs a fix

Comment: Cheers Alasdair! You spotted the problem very well.

Answer (score 5):

```
aquotelist = Quote.objects.filter(author__author_name__exact = name)
```

Try changing the corresponding line to the above. The way you have it now, you are matching `author` to the given name, but `author` is probably considered by its ID here, definitely not by its `author_name`. The format is as follows:

```
Quote.objects.filter([model]__[field]__exact = [whatever])
```

Comment: Thanks, I would remember the syntax of filter to avoid similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced and solved similar issue, 
focus on attribute :    `author = models.ForeignKey(Author)`
django expect that you pass an Instance of `Author` class to the `author` field. When you search django want to get a id (a integer number of this Instance):
so to get :

```
aquotelist = Quote.objects.filter(author__exact = name)
```

you have to start by :

1. create `obj_Author = Author.objects.get(author_name = name)`
2. `aquotelist = Quote.objects.get(author__exact = obj_Author.id)`

PS: ( I used `get()` in my example but if you expect to get multiple record, you can you use `filter()` and modify something. but main point is that because you work with a "`ForeignKey` field" so you need to give it a `id` like `obj_Author.id`. )

Comment: This answer requires 2 seperate DB queries. Look at some of the other answers that only use one. They will be much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reset your migrate , you can see this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768217/9533909

i hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and I figured out that I made records in the DB table that in your case is (Quote) before making the foreign key relationship with (Author) then after making the foreign key relationship Django doesn't know what to do to handle the old data in Quote model (to which records in Author should old records be assigned to)

--> The simplest solution is to:

delete your old Quote records: `Quote.objects.all().delete` inside your shell

recreate and reassign its new records correctly

makemigrations, migrate and runserver ... done

Answer (score -7):

This will fix your problem permanently ::go to your directory

```
C:\python 37\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields
```

and edit the file `__init__.py` and edit line 1807; replace

```
return int(value)
```

with

```
return int()
```

So just delete the argument **value** then your program will except all field references.

Comment: This answer must be deleted, it may misguide some junior developers. First, never ever directly modify some library files, especially for large thing like Django. Second, this fix will make any `int` field queries fail by not using the correct value