# django urls() invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, django

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548023/django-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10) with no success.

I have a review website and I am trying to post all reviews by a specific username. i.e. ".../reviews/user/username".

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^reviews/user/(?P<username>\w+)$', views.user_review_list, name='user_review_list'),
]
```

views.py (User_Name is the name of the column in the database):

```
def user_review_list(request, username):
    latest_review_list = Review.objects.filter(User_Name=username).order_by('-Pub_Date')
    context = {'latest_review_list': latest_review_list, 'User_Name': username}
    return render(request, 'bourbons/user_review_list.html', context)
```

And the html file where I call it:

```
<h5>Rated {{ review.Rating }} of 5 by <u><a href="{% url 'app:user_review_list' review.User_Name %}" style="color:#ffffff">
    {{ review.User_Name }}
</a></u></h5>
```

I have found a couple of other posts with different methods and I still keep getting the error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user/username'". I feel that the error is at or even before the urls.py portion cause I have changed the views.py function several times and the error hasnt changed.

I am using Django version 1.11.6.

Thanks

Here is the extra from the feedbacks...

Main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^facts', views.facts, name='facts'),
    url(r'^contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls', 
namespace='app')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', 
namespace="auth")),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

App urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.bourbon_list, name='app_list'),
    url(r'^app/(?P<ID>.+)$', views.app_detail, name='app_detail'),
    url(r'^reviews$', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    url(r'^reviews/(?P<RatingID>.+)$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
    url(r'^reviews/user/(?P<username>\w+)$', views.user_review_list, name='user_review_list'),

]
```

models.py

```
class Review(models.Model):

    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),)

    RatingID = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Item = models.ForeignKey(App)
    Pub_Date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    User_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the urlpattern for `review_detail` to

```
url(r'^reviews/(?P<RatingID>\d+)$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
```

What's happening is that the existing urlpattern regex  for this view is matching any other urls underneath `reviews/`, because of the subsequent `.+`.