# Django filter - Multiple value

Tags: python, django, filter

so a have little problem:

```
genres = (x, y, z,...)
search = Movie.filter(Q(genres=x) | Q(genres=y| ...)
```

I can filter by that in django and have in one variable like this
but i dont know how many variables will genres have. So it is possible to that at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not `Movie.objects.filter(genres__in=genres)`?

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter)

Comment: This great idea, but we i used it i have error:
invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: @AndrzejDerela maybe this SO answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548023/django-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10