# How can I redirect users from list_view_template to detail_view_template in Django, by using slug from foreign_key and item_id together?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am creating an image gallery in Django. Gallery consist of albums and pictures in each album.

The goal is:

1. To have albums, albums have a slug.
2. To have a list view for each album with pictures belonging in that album.
3. To display album name in every album.
4. To have a detail view for each picture, the picture itself has an id, but no slug, however, the url of detail view should have album slug followed by image id.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

In Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class AlbumManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AlbumManager, self).filter(active=True)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    objects = AlbumManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('album_details', args=[self.slug])


class Picture(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='pictures_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album.name

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
            return reverse('picture_details', kwargs={'album': self.album.slug, 'id': self.id})
```

In my Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Album, Picture


def album_details(request, album):
    albums = Album.objects.active() # needed for navbar dropdown menu
    pictures = Album.objects.get(slug=album).pictures_set.all()
    print('PICTURES: ', pictures)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'albums': albums, 'pictures':pictures})


def picture_details(request, slug, id):
    albums = Album.objects.active() # needed for navbar dropdown menu
    image = get_object_or_404(Picture, slug=slug, id=id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'image ': image , 'albums': albums})
```

In Urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import album_details, picture_details


urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:album>/', album_details, name='album_details'),
    path('<slug:album>/<int:id>/', picture_details, name='picture_details'),
]
```

In my list.html:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{albums.name}}</h1>
      <section class="layout-multicolumn container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-uppercase">
          {% for b in pictures %}
            <section class="mb-5 col-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                <a href="{{ b.get_absolute_url }}"><img class="layout-image img-fluid" src="{{ b.image.url }}"></a>
                <p>{{b.description}}</p>
            </section>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </section>      
{% endblock %}
```

In detail.html:

```
{% block content %}
  <div>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ image.image.url }}">
    {{ image.description }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And navbar dropdown code in base.html:

```
            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Vårt Arbeid</a>
                <section class="dropdown-menu">
                    {% for a in albums %}
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{a.get_absolute_url}}">{{a.name}}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </section>
            </div>
```

I can't redirect from list_view to detail_view. That is my main problem. Can you see what I do wrong? I have tried print statements and what I figured out is that it doesn't redirect from list to detail. After hours of playing around with the code I got a new error message... Right now error message says:

> Reverse for 'picture_details' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'bel',
> 'id': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['pictures/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

and

> picture_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'album'.

and if I change slug to album in **picture_details(request, album, id):**
and change album=album in **get_object_or_404(Picture, album=album, id=id)**
I get error message:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'bel'

**Error messages change every time as I adjust slug and id variables. I am sure problem lie within album_slug and picture_id in urls.py and views.py, and causes errors for templates...**

It is probably a bad question, please forgive me. If you know Django, can you see what I am doing wrong? Why can't I redirect? Is it because I use album slug in list view and detail view doesn't see that slug from list_view? There are so many possibilities for what I am doing wrong, please take a look and help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you only mistake was the name of the first param in the url, try this:

```py
class Picture(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('picture_details', kwargs={'album': self.album.slug, 'id': self.id})
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Sorry this code is a mess and I am not good at this. Actually my first param was that, before I tried something I saw on internet, and now it is back at previous error, now it gives error_message: **picture_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'album'.**  And I guess detail_view cant see selected album from the list_view where the slug is... I can't redirect from the list_view into detail_view. Can you see how this redirection can be made?

Comment: now try to change the detail view to this: `def picture_details(request, album, id):` or  this `def picture_details(request, album=None, id=None):`

Comment: I did, and also changed, slug to album **get_object_or_404(Picture, album=album, id=id)** , I have tried that before, it gives another error: **invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'bel'** the 'bel' is the name of the album and is a slug, somehow Django sees it as int(), I have tried in urls.py to change **'<slug:album>/<int:id>/** to **<str:album>/<int:id>/** without any success, it gives same invalid literal for int() error.   I don't understand why it wants a slug to be int(). It is probably something with transition from one view to another.

Comment: And I have also tried to apply solution found here, without any success [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548023/django-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: now the error is in this line: `image = get_object_or_404(Picture, slug=slug, id=id)` try with one of this two options: `image = get_object_or_404(Picture, id=id)` or `image = get_object_or_404(Picture, album__slug=slug, id=id)`